# Asp.Identity OWIN Cookie not Authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Below is the code I use to sign in. It comes back and says success. But If I tried to get the UserID, or do a User.Identity.IsAuthenticated on any page, it says false.

I can't figure out what could be going on here.

```
var SignInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

        var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, false, true);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                Response.Redirect(User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "~/Admin/Dashboard.aspx" : "~/User/Dashboard.aspx");
                break;
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Lockout");
                break;
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Unknown",true);
                break;
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                txtErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
                break;
        }
```

It's almost like its saying Success, but its really not working correctly.
I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing seems to keep me authenticated at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try use SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, true, true);

The third parameter should set true, because if this parameter is false the browser will don't know  that it is authenticated.

In summary on methotd is written:

> isPersistent:
>           //     Flag indicating whether the sign-in cookie should persist after the browser is
>           //     closed.

Comment: "persist after the browser is closed", I don't think that is the OP's issue.

Comment: Its true, in my project i used equals written in this question but only change is this parameter

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, changing this:

```
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, false, true);
```

to this fixed it, have no idea why.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, false, true);
```